# Auto increment ids starting at 1 per tenant in a single database

Tags: c#, sql-server, multi-tenant

I am creating a tenant portal application using a single database. Yes, I already weighed the pros and cons of using a single database vs splitting them out.

All of my tables have an Id (int), TenantId (int).

Is there any possible way to make it so each tenant starts at id:1 for each table?

For example I would like:
(Project Table)
Tenant 1
Id: 1, TenantId: 1
Id: 2, TenantId: 1
Id: 3, TenantId: 1

Tenant 2
Id: 1, TenantId: 2
Id: 2, TenantId: 2
Id: 3, TenantId: 2

---

rather than:
Tenant 2
Id: 4, TenantId: 2
Id: 5, TenantId: 2
Id: 6, TenantId: 2

I already thought about using guids, but I hate the way they look in the url.
I wonder if it would be possible to use guids as the unique id, but shield it from the user and only ever show them the id. Then I would need some kind of mechanism to manually increment the id column properly in my code.

Just trying to figure out how someone would handle this from experience. Can it be done purely in sql server?

Comment: Have you tough about simply hiding the url ?

Comment: @squillman I do have a Tenant table that has my tenants in it, with their unique Ids. My problem is with the data tables.

Comment: Is there any reason the id's really matter other than visually in the url? Seems like this would be a lot of work managing composite id's for very little benefit.

Comment: You are way overthinking this. You should NEVER design your database around what the value looks like in a URL. You design your database to model the data.

Comment: @bhmahler This is true, I guess if I go with the approach that I never show the user the Id anywhere in the UI besides in the URL to help me with the web app.

Comment: @SeanLange It is a lot easy to develop a web app when you can rely on these values in the url going from page to page. Even when using Angular. I am starting to think that I shouldn't worry about what the user sees as the Id in the url as long as it isn't in the UI.

Comment: `UPDATE tenants SET next_project_id += 1 OUTPUT deleted.next_project_id WHERE tenant_id = @`. This approach is not recommended if a "project" is actually something that can be inserted hundreds of times per second by multiple sessions.

Comment: Not sure what your last comment means. But again, you don't design the database so it is easy to code. If anything using a guid makes it difficult to guess query string values so users can't just start viewing other data by injecting data in through the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a composite primary key?  That would allow you to enter the ID value you want, which you could easily figure out with a table lookup..

Comment: If I go this path, I will need to increment the ID value in my code rather than with SQLServer correct?

Comment: Yes, since the auto-increment ID would do as you describe as the scenario you do not want.  A simple check for count of the tennant id in sql would work too I think.

Comment: I got ya, the guys above in the comments are convincing me to just not worry about it since I will never be listing the Id of any entities on the actual UI. Just in the Url. It will save me a lot of headache.

Comment: IE: insert into table(id, tennantid) values((Select count(*)+1 from table where tennantid = [tennantid]) ,[tennantid])

Comment: Ok, and set Id and TenantId as a composite key with no auto increment? Letting the code do the auto increment. Correct?

Comment: COUNT(\*) + 1 won't work because what if you insert 1,2,3,4 and then delete 3? You'll insert 4 again. You need serializable MAX+1, which inhibits concurrency, and another complication is if you create 4, then delete 4, is it okay to re-use that number? I agree with the others - your users shouldn't care what ID is assigned to their project, because they should be identifying it by name. If you care about what appears in the URL, *stop using the URL*. It just makes people want to mess with it anyway ("I wonder what's in project 354? Here, I can try.")

Comment: True you could just URL Rewrite, make a link out of other fields, IE: [FirstName]-[LastName]-[TennantID] or w/e.  Lots of ways to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table that store sequences and a stored procedure to get the next sequence value.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Sequence]
(
    [TenantId] INT,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(60),
    [NextValue] INT,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Sequence] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [TenantId] ASC,
        [Name] ASC
    )
);
GO;


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextSequenceValue]
    @tenantId INT,
    @name NVARCHAR(60)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnValue INT = 1;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [Sequence]
    SET @returnValue = [NextValue], [NextValue] = [NextValue] + 1
    WHERE [TenantId] = @tenantId AND [Name] = @name;

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Sequence]
            ([TenantId], [Name], [NextValue])
        VALUES
            (@tenantId, @name, @returnValue);
    END;

    RETURN @returnValue;
END;
GO;
```

You call the stored procedure in code when adding a new entity. Another option is to use an INSERT trigger to call the stored procedure right in SQL Server.